# Passing extra parameters in JQGrid delete with multiselect

Tags: jqgrid, multi-select

I want to have delete functionality in my JQGrid for deleting multiple rows. My code looks like this:

```
    {height:180,mtype:"POST",closeAfterDel:true, url:'gridedit.jsp',reloadAfterSubmit:true,

 onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
      var rowData = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
      var params ={amount:rowData.amount,account:rowData.account.replace(/-/g,"")};

      return params;

   },

   afterSubmit: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'});
    return [true,'']; 
}
```

}

I want to make deletions as per the values of the column **rowData.account**

The problem is that when I select multiple rows, I can see that the grid passes all the rowid's back to the edit URL, but only passes the rowData.account value of the first row !

Is there a way to make the grid pass back all the values? I cant delete based on the row id on the back end as my database does not have any row id's.

Please help.

Here is my grid code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

  datatype: 'json',
  url:'gridfeeder.jsp?ctlSelectedDate=<%= request.getParameter("ctlSelectedDate")%>',

  colNames: ['Date', 'Account ', 'Amount', 'Code'],
  colModel: [

             //First Column, DATE

  {name: 'adate', index: 'adate', width: 300, sorttype: 'date', align: 'center',datefmt: 'Y-m-d',
 editable:true, formatter: myLinkFormatter, editoptions:{

     dataInit:function(elem)
      {
     jQuery(elem).datepicker({

         showButtonPanel: true,
         changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true

     });
}}, search:true, stype:'text',searchoptions:{

     dataInit:function(elem)
      {
     jQuery(elem).datepicker({

         showButtonPanel: true,
         changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true

     });
}

 }

  },
            //Second Column, ACCOUNT

            { name: 'account', index: 'account', width: 300, align: 'center', sorttype: 'string', editable:true,
    search:true, stype:'text',editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:

        //Validation for this column for editing

        function(value, colname) {
        if (value.length<9 || value.length>11) 
               return [false,"Invalid Input"];
            else 
               return [true,""];
            }
    },
    searchrules:{custom:true, custom_func:
```

//Validation for this column for searching

```
        function(val, colname) {
        if (val.length<9 || val.length>11) 
               return [false,"Invalid Input"];
            else 
               return [true,""];
            }
    }
  },

            //Third Column, AMOUNT

  { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 300, align: 'center', sorttype: 'float', editable:true,
    editrules:{number:true}, search:true, stype:'text'
  },

            //Fourth Column, CODE

  { name: 'code', index: 'code', width: 300, align: 'center', sorttype: 'float', editable:true,
    search:true, stype:'text'
  }

  ],

  pager: "#pager",      //Identifying the navigation bar
  rowNum: 500,          // how many rows to display on page 1
  rowList: [500,1000, 2000, 3000,4000], //values for the dropdown which specifies how many rows to show 
  sortorder: "desc", //the order of sorting by default
  viewrecords: true, // displays total number of rows
  gridview: true,
  autoencode: true,
  height:400, //height of the grid
  ignoreCase:true,// case insensitive search
  multiselect:true, // checkboxes before each row
  multiboxonly: true,
  loadonce:true, //for client side sorting, searching and pagination
  caption:"This is me" // caption for the grid header
```

here is the navgrid section :

```
    }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true},

// Options for EDIT 

    {height:280,mtype: "POST",closeAfterEdit: true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, url:'gridedit.jsp',

        recreateForm: true, 

        //set some properties beofre the dialog box is seen by the user

        beforeShowForm: function(form) {

            /*$('#adate',form).attr('readonly','readonly');
            $('#account',form).attr('readonly','readonly');*/

            $('#adate',form).hide();
            $('#account',form).hide();
        },

        // what happens when the user clicks submit. passing extra parameters

           onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {

               var rowid = postdata[this.id + "_id"]; // postdata.list_id

               var dataF = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowid, 'account');

            return {account:dataF.replace(/-/g,"")};
            },

           // changing the datatype

         afterSubmit: function () {
            $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
            return [true,''];
        }

    },

    //ADD options

    {height:280,mtype:"POST", closeAfterAdd:true, reloadAfterSubmit:true, url:'gridedit.jsp',


beforeShowForm: function(form) {

    /*var cm = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getColProp','adate');
    alert(cm);
    cm.editable = false;
    $('#adate',form).attr('readonly','readonly');
    $('#account',form).attr('readonly','readonly');*/
    $('#adate',form).show();
    $('#account',form).show();
},

    //Change the datatype

afterSubmit: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
    return [true, ""];
}
    },

    {height:180,mtype:"POST",closeAfterDel:true, url:'gridedit.jsp',reloadAfterSubmit:true,

/* onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
      var rowData = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
      var params ={account:rowData.account.replace(/-/g,"")};

      return params;

   },*/

   delData: {
       account: function() {
                  var sel_id = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                  var value = $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'account');
                  return value.replace(/-/g,"");
             }
      },
   afterSubmit: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'});
    return [true,'']; 
}

    }

    );

  function myLinkFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

      return "<a href='account094act.jsp?GETDATE=" + cellvalue + "&GETACC=" + rowObject[1] + "'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
  }

  jQuery("#refresh_list").click(function(){
        jQuery("#list").setGridParam({datatype: 'json'});
        jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One uses mostly unique values which are the best for your situation as rowids. Probably you should consider to use the value from `account` column as rowid? You don't posted the full code of jqGrid which you you and don't posted JSON/XML data used for filling the grid. So it's difficult to give an exact advice to you.

You can consider to place `key: true` property in `colModel` in the definition of the column `account`. If all values from the column are unique (the values are different in all rows of the grid) then you can use the settings. In the case the rowid (the value of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements of the grid) will be assigned the same as the values from `account` column.

All editing operation sends id of the editing row. So you will get `account` sent to the server. In case of `multiselect: true` jqGrid send comma separated list of rowids. In your case you will get on the server comma separated list of deleted accounts. Probably you can get all other information (like `amount`), if it's required, based on the `account` value. If `account` value are really unique and you have *all data* on the server that you can get *any* information which corresponds to `account` chosen.

Comment: hi oleg, thanks for your response. i am using JSON data. right now when i click on the delete button after selecting multiple rows, nothing happens ! there is no data being sent to the server at all. i'm pretty sure that it is supposed to send at least athe id's of all the rows. i did it once, a long time back but i dont remember now.

Comment: can you see anything that I am missing ? Is there something I need to specify so that the delete button works for multiple selections ?

Comment: It's clear that you should get `selarrrow` array instead of `selrow` option inside of `delData.account`. If really nothing will be send to the server (no post to `gridedit.jsp`) then you could *debug* the code. You can set breakpoint inside of `delData.account` and on lines below `$("#dData","#"+dtbl+"_2").click(function(){`. I hope you use already `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and will easy find the required lines of jqGrid code.

Comment: hi oleg, i made some minor changes. i put key:true for my account column and now i get a comma separated list of account numbers being passed to the back end. this greatly simplifies my problem as i no longer have to explicitly send the account number. the only problem is when i try to access the elements of this array by using        String[] k=request.getParameter("id");        it shows an error saying type mismatch. When I do               String k=request.getParameter("id");        then there is no error, but I am only able to access the last element sent.

Comment: How can i access the entire array on the back end ?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I had a bug in my code. I've figured it out exactly how I want it to work. Thanks a lot man :)

Comment: @user2334092: You are welcome! In C# the statement `var ids = request.getParameter("id");` should have `string` type and you can use `Split` method: `var idArray = ids.Split(new char[] {','});` now you can iterate over the items of `idArray`. If your problem is solved now, then you probably wrote such or close code.